# Install iuiAutomation c#

Tags: c#

I am having some issues installing IUIAutomation if anyone could head me in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated. I'm attempting to get tab information from Microsoft edge

Answer (score 0):

I could be totally wrong, I just started working with UI Automation myself, but as far as I understood [IUIAutomation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671406(v=vs.85).aspx) is working with C++, whereas the managed [UI Automation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation?view=netframework-4.7.1) is for usage with C#. I played a bit around with UI Automation in C#, but for some reason I don't know, I don't get all the events. This is because I'm going to look into IUIAutomation next.

If you'd like to use UI Automation with C# you have to add it (UIAutomationClient and UIAutomationTypes) as references in your Visual Studio project.

I hope my answer helps a bit.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access the "IUIAutomationElement" or similar declarations, you'll need to reference the COM version of the UIAutomationClient (v1.0).  You can find it on the same Reference Manager window as the .NET Framework version (using VS2017), you just need to search under the COM section instead of the Assemblies section.

If you're just looking to access "AutomationElement", you should be ok using the .NET Framework version.  I mainly try to use this one, unless I need to access the LegacyIAccessible values without using a wrapper.

Let me know if this doesn't help, or you need more info.